# When WordPress Does Not Provide an .htaccess File for New Multisite Sites because of CPanel Fantastico Auto-Installer?

Tags: installation, htaccess

I have installed WordPress via an auto-installer and later configured it as multisite. But whenever I create the WordPress site using auto-installer it doesn't give me the `.htaccess` file by default. So I've created an empty file with the name `.htaccess` in CPanel and pasted this code in to it:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files 
RewriteRule ^files/(.+)wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
[OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Is it a right method ?

Comment: Please consider to better format your question. The title could use some better wording as well. I have problems to understand you properly so it's hard to help. But I think your question is valid, so if you can improve it, I'll give it a point.

Comment: *@hakre* - I edited for him. You could do the same. Poor formatting reflects badly on the site more than it reflect badly on a *@user402* with 1 reputation point. So rather than wait on them who may never, just do it (and leave them a comment asking them to do it next time.)

Comment: I am extremely sorry for poor formatting of the question.I will improve making my questions clear .
Sorry again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is not a problem. As long as you site works and redirects to the right pages there is no harm in doing this. You might also want to use it for protecting your wp-config file from hackers by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
<Files wp-config.php>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</Files>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you !
I will add this code to wp-config.php file .

Comment: @user402: You add it to your `.htaccess` file, not to `wp-config.php`. It tells the server to deny access to `wp-config.php`. If you ever disable PHP for some reason, this will prevent the server from sending it as a plain text file, with your password in it.

Comment: Sorry I have mistyped here in this comment.I have added it to .htaccess file successfully .

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess file should be automatically created by wordpress when you activate pretty permalinks. In case it did not, wordpress will show you the code you should use to create the file manually.

If you're in doubt which code to use, I would disable pretty permalinks in the backend, back-up and then remove the current .htaccess file. Then I would go into the backend to activate pretty permalinks again and follow the instructions given.